# Passing message from root view controller to another view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a navigation root view controller, which I am pushing to another view controller.

The view controller will determine the third pushed controller based on what button was pressed in root view controller. Based on this, how can I send a message through delegate from the root view controller to the second view controller 2 that either button 1 or button 2 has been pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the difference is a change in state for the application, either create a property on your application delegate, or create a manager class to handle your application state.  Set the property / notify the manager when you touch the button in your root view controller, then check this value when your third view controller loads.

If the difference is merely that are navigating to a different area of the app, create a property on your second view controller and your third view controller.  When you touch the button in your root view controller, set the property on the second view controller.  When you navigate from the second view controller to the third view controller, set the property on the third view controller before you push it onto the stack.

Comment: Jim, I got the concept of rather just create a property such as a BOOL, and check if either one or the another, what I am not getting is how do I send the message from rootviewController to the Viewcontroller 2 property to set it either "1" or "0".

Comment: When your button is pressed, are you creating and pushing the second view controller?  You can just set the property on the second view controller after you create it and before you push it.

Comment: Aah makes sense.. If I want to take another route through delegates, is there way to do that way?

Comment: How would you want to use a delegate in this situation?

Comment: Well, my rootViewController is what my first stack of navigation controller, which is being set on my appdelegate. Maybe I could create a property there for delegate with respect to navigation controller and set and get the messeage from different controllers? This will just make things more centralized and not bind with one controller, I guess.